# Eliminar elementos duplicados y obtener array de elementos en MySql en tablas con relacion muchos a muchos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy intentando realizar una consulta a varias a la vez, de las cuales tengo las tabla:
*colors que registra todos los colores (varios) de cada producto con una relacion de muchos a muchos
*la tabla companies con una relacion de uno a muchos que registra la compañia que pertenece a cada producto
*y la tabla categories, con una relacion de muchos a muchos que registra las categorias (varias) que puede pertenecer a cada producto.

El problema es que cuando hago el SELECT me devuelve el registro varias veces por cada registro en la tabla relacionada, Ej: un producto tiene 3 colores, me devuelve el producto 3 veces donde solo cambia el color.

estoy tratando de eliminar los registros duplicados y que me devuelva una array en cada tabla como colores:
ej: si un producto tiene 3 colores, que me devuelva una columna colors con un array de todos los colores.

El problema es que funciona con los colores, pero en los demas campos me devuelve un array con los elementos duplicados. hay una forma otra forma de solucionar esto?

Nota: estoy usando Mysql

```
SELECT 
    p.id,
    p.description,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG( c.name) AS colors,
    comp.name as company,
    JSON_ARRAYAGG( cat.name) as categories
FROM 
    product AS p
JOIN 
    product_colors AS pc ON p.id = pc.product_id
JOIN 
    colors AS c ON pc.colors_id = c.id
JOIN 
    companies as comp ON p.company_id = comp.company_id
JOIN 
    product_categories pcat ON p.id = pcat.product_id
JOIN 
    categories as cat ON pcat.categories_id = cat.id
GROUP BY 
    p.id, p.description, comp.name;
```

resultado
Columna colors esta bien, pero se dublican los resultados de company y categories estan duplicados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna forma de obtener una array para los campos colors, categories al hacer la consulta y evitar los elementos ducplicados?. gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tu consulta se ve bien. Intentaste hacer un SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Yo no veo nada duplicado ahi.. porque pensas que tenes el mismo registro, cuando los ID son claramente diferentes?

Comment: SI YA LO INTENTE PERO me da un error de sintaxis, no lo esta reconociendo mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible que el fallo este en la versión de tu server MYSQL (la función JSON_ARRAYAG está disponible desde la versión MYSQL 5.7.22) si eso no te sirve prueba a usar GROUP_CONCAT junto a DISTINCT de la siguiente manera:

```
  
SELECT 
    p.id,
    p.description,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.name) AS colors,
    comp.name AS company,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cat.name) AS categories
FROM 
    product AS p
JOIN 
    product_colors AS pc ON p.id = pc.product_id
JOIN 
    colors AS c ON pc.colors_id = c.id
JOIN 
    companies AS comp ON p.company_id = comp.company_id
JOIN 
    product_categories pcat ON p.id = pcat.product_id
JOIN 
    categories AS cat ON pcat.categories_id = cat.id
GROUP BY 
    p.id, p.description, comp.name;
```

Comment: Perfecto brother, me funciono perfectamente. estoy usando la version 8.0.33 de Mysql, estoy usando DBngin para el motor y MySQL Workbench en mac... me hubiera gustado tener una forma de convertirlo en array directamente, pero nada, que se puede hacer. Mill gracias men.